# process data with numpy seems rather slow than pure python?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, comparative-review, numpy

In my opinion, Vectorization operation with numpy should be much faster than use for in pure python. I write two function to get and process data in a csv file, one in numpy and another in pure python, but numpy one takes nearly four times time of the other. Why? Is this the "wrong" way to  numpy? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

The python code is below, while csv file in rather long, and I put it to [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/jjwt/de4e75b81ced840183b7c8cbea3e1644)

The csv file includes some info about an engine, in which, the first column means crankshaft angle in degrees, and the 8th column means (header "PCYL_1") means the first cylinder pressure in bar.

what I want to do:

1. get angle-pressure data pairs with only integer angle,
2. group the data by angle, and get the max pressure of each angle
3. get new angle-max_pressure data pairs
4. shift angle range from -360~359 to 0~719
5. sort data-pairs by angle
6. because angle range must be 0~720, and first pressure equals last pressure,
   add a [720.0, first angle] to data pairs
7. output data pairs to a dat file

my run eviroment is

1. python3.6.4 MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)
2. win8.1 64 bit

I i run ipython in the script file direcotry and input below:

```
from gen_cylinder_pressure_data_from_csv import *
In [5]: %timeit main_pure_python()
153 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each

In [6]: %timeit main_with_numpy()
627 ms ± 3.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

python code is below:

```
from glob import glob
import numpy


def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        headers = None
        for line_number, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
            if line_number == 0:
                headers = line.strip().split(',')
                angle_index = headers.index('曲轴转角')
                # cylinder_pressure_indexes = [i for i in range(len(headers)) if headers[i].startswith('PCYL_1')]
                cylinder_pressure_indexes = [i for i in range(len(headers)) if headers[i].startswith('PCYL_1')]
            elif line_number == 1:
                continue
            else:
                data = line.strip()
                if data != '':
                    datas = data.split(',')
                    angle = datas[angle_index]
                    if '.' not in angle:
                        # cylinder_pressure = max(datas[i] for i in cylinder_pressure_indexes)
                        cylinder_pressure = datas[cylinder_pressure_indexes[0]]
                        # if angle == '17':
                        # print(angle, cylinder_pressure)
                        yield angle, cylinder_pressure


def write_data(filename):
    data_dic = {}
    for angle, cylinder_pressure in get_data(filename):
        k = int(angle)
        v = float(cylinder_pressure)
        if k in data_dic:
            data_dic[k].append(v)
        else:
            data_dic[k] = [v]
    for k, v in data_dic.items():
        # datas_dic[k] = sum(v) / len(v)
        data_dic[k] = max(v)
    angles = sorted(data_dic.keys())
    if angles[-1] - angles[0] != 720:
        data_dic[angles[0] + 720] = data_dic[angles[0]]
        angles.append(angles[0] + 720)
    else:
        print(angles[0], angles[-1])
    with open('%srpm.dat' % filename[-8:-4], 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for k in angles:
            # print('%s,%s\n' % (k,datas_dic[k]))
            f.write('%s,%s\n' % (k, data_dic[k]))


def main_with_numpy():
    # rather slow than main_pure_python
    for filename in glob('Ten*.csv'):
        with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            data_array = numpy.loadtxt(f, delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 7), skiprows=2)[::10]
            pressure_array = data_array[:, 1]
            pressure_array = pressure_array.reshape(720, pressure_array.shape[0] // 720)
            pressure_array = numpy.amax(pressure_array, axis=1, keepdims=True)
            data_output = numpy.zeros((721, 2), )
            data_output[:-1, 0] = data_array[:720, 0]
            data_output[:-1, 1] = pressure_array.reshape(720)
            data_output[:, 0] = (data_output[:, 0] + 720) % 720
            data_output[-1, 0] = 721
            data_output = data_output[data_output[:, 0].argsort()]
            data_output[-1] = data_output[0]
            data_output[-1, 0] = 720.0
            with open('%srpm.dat' % filename[-8:-4], 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                numpy.savetxt(f, data_output, fmt='%f', delimiter=',')
            pass


def main_pure_python():
    for filename in glob('Ten*.csv'):
        write_data(filename)
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_pure_python()
```

Comment: We need to know what your program is doing. Could you explain these calculations etc?

Comment: thank you for replying, i've edit the content and list what i want to do. @t3chb0t

Comment: ok, grea; I'd be even better if you also could add your measurements because you're saying that one method is faster than the other... is the difference in seconds or minutes? Oh, and the python version tag is what we need to.

Comment: measurements and python version added. @t3chb0t

Comment: `loadtxt` and `savetxt` don't make much use of compiled `numpy`.  They use python file io. Their performance and code has been discussed on SO many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I am also newbie on numpy, but your question interested me, so I did some profile check on your code also google some about numpy. Here is what I found

**The main reason why you numpy solution is so slow is because of `numpy.loadtxt`**

---

### Profiler Result

Here is the profiler result from your `main_with_numpy` function

```
1562753 function calls (1476352 primitive calls) in 1.624 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.004    0.004    1.624    1.624 gen_cylinder_pressure_data_from_csv.py:55(main_with_numpy)
        1    0.032    0.032    1.609    1.609 npyio.py:765(loadtxt)
        3    0.430    0.143    1.545    0.515 npyio.py:994(read_data)
    86401    0.144    0.000    0.452    0.000 npyio.py:982(split_line)
    86400    0.086    0.000    0.316    0.000 npyio.py:1019(<listcomp>)
172800/86400    0.228    0.000    0.243    0.000 npyio.py:966(pack_items)
...
```

And result from your `main_pure_python` function

```
195793 function calls (195785 primitive calls) in 0.241 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.241    0.241 gen_cylinder_pressure_data_from_csv.py:76(main_pure_python)
        1    0.015    0.015    0.240    0.240 gen_cylinder_pressure_data_from_csv.py:31(write_data)
     8641    0.078    0.000    0.224    0.000 gen_cylinder_pressure_data_from_csv.py:7(get_data)
    86401    0.082    0.000    0.082    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.042    0.042    0.050    0.050 {method 'readlines' of '_io._IOBase' objects}
```

**Almost 8 times slower** and check the `npyio.py:765(loadtxt)` cost most of the time

You used generator in your `main_pure_python` to read data, so to eliminate the effect from *loadtxt* so I check the part of the function **after** load data

Here is the result

With numpy

```
2917 function calls in 0.008 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.008    0.008 gen_cylinder_pressure_data_from_csv.py:81(deal_data_numpy)
        1    0.004    0.004    0.006    0.006 npyio.py:1143(savetxt)
```

Without numpy

```
9369 function calls in 0.011 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.009    0.009    0.011    0.011 gen_cylinder_pressure_data_from_csv.py:44(deal_data)
     7921    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
      720    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
```

with numpy is slightly faster.

---

### Why `numpy.loadtxt` is slow

Sorry I can't help you review your numpy code. But I google about this question why `numpy.loadtxt` so slow.

[Here is the original link](http://akuederle.com/stop-using-numpy-loadtxt)

> Seriously, stop using the numpy.loadtxt() function (unless you have a
>   lot of spare time…). Why you might ask? - Because it is SLOW! - How
>   slow you might ask? - Very slow! Numpy loads a 250 mb csv-file
>   containing 6215000 x 4 datapoints from my SSD in approx. 35 s!

[Another relative links about this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259393/numpy-loading-csv-too-slow-compared-to-matlab)

So as mentioned in these links `pandas` might be better choice for you to read csv file or leave it to just pure python

Comment: Thank you very much ! I've never thought of file io as the key! i use profile in ipython and get the similar result, both main_pure_python and main_with_numpy take much time in get data, whie numpy.loadtext even worse.